# How to make ngFor faster?

Tags: angular

**TrackBy didn't help.**

There is dropdown after click on it, there should be rendered more then 7000 < li > elements.

Code:

```
<li *ngFor="let option of arrayOfOptions | nanoSearchByKey:searchString:displayProperty; trackBy: trackByFn">
```

Currently behaviour is that after open dropdown browser freeze on 15 sec.

Please if someone have some idea, resources, post like this... which are related with my problem. 
Share with me.

Comment: Shorten the list....

Comment: How to shorten the list -> create custom component, which will listen for scroll event and load new items when scroll to end.

Comment: @KeshanNageswaran Cool, thanks.

Comment: And you want to say that someone actually scrolls trough that 7k entries to get something required? Sure.... cuz why not right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **pagination** for the the data and just display the first 500 elemnt,no one will read the 7000 element of data.